# Refactoring LINQ query to accommodate null values / missing properties

Tags: linq, refactoring

I have a string array which has a variable number of properties that I need to parse. I’m using LINQ to parse this data but can’t help thinking there’s a more efficient/elegant way to achieve this than duplicate the LINQ as I have done.
Is there an inherent way to account for NULL values (because the property may or may not be present in the array) than I am doing here:

```
MyCollection.StringArray
    .Where(e => e.name == "aproperty") != null 
      ? MyCollection.StringArray.Where(e => e.name == "aproperty") FirstOrDefault().value 
      : string.Empty;
```

Ultimately, all I want to do is pull the value from the property if it exists in the collection, else I need an empty string (or null). However, I don’t want any exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: That does not compile. Please provide compiling code or at least code which shows clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You have StringArray? or you have your own object list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the exception that you get if you're trying to access an empty sequence, you can use `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
string value = MyCollection.StringArray
    .Where(e => e.name == "aproperty")
    .Select(e => e.value)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
    .First();
```

It's important to select the `value` property first which is safe even if it doesn't exist. With `DefaultIfEmpty` you can  use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.